# How to convert a mllib matrix to a spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, matrix, apache-spark-mllib, apache-zeppelin

I want to pretty print the result of a correlation in a zeppelin notebook:

```
val Row(coeff: Matrix) = Correlation.corr(data, "features").head
```

One of the ways to achieve this is to convert the result into a DataFrame with each value in a separate column and call `z.show()`.

However, looking into the [Matrix api](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/Matrix.html) I don't see any way to do this.

Is there another straight forward way to achieve this?

Edit:

The dataframe has 50 columns. Just converting to a string would not help as the output get truncated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`toString`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/Matrix.html#toString-int-int-) method should be the easiest and fastest way if you simply want to print the matrix. You can change the output by inputting the maximum number of lines to print as well as max line width. You can change the formatting by splitting on new lines and ",". For example:

```
val matrix = Matrices.dense(2,3, Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0))
matrix.toString
  .split("\n")
  .map(_.trim.split(" ").filter(_ != "").mkString("[", ",", "]"))
  .mkString("\n")
```

which will give the following:

```
[1.0,3.0,5.0]
[2.0,4.0,6.0]
```

---

However, if you want to convert the matrix to an DataFrame, the easiest way would be to first create an `RDD` and then use `toDF()`.

```
val matrixRows = matrix.rowIter.toSeq.map(_.toArray)
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(matrixRows).toDF("Row")
```

Then to put each value in a separate column you can do the following

```
val numOfCols = matrixRows.head.length
val df2 = (0 until numOfCols).foldLeft(df)((df, num) => 
    df.withColumn("Col" + num, $"Row".getItem(num)))
  .drop("Row")
df2.show(false)
```

Result using the example data:

```
+----+----+----+
|Col0|Col1|Col2|
+----+----+----+
|1.0 |3.0 |5.0 |
|2.0 |4.0 |6.0 |
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of this helps me. The dataframe has 50 columns and they get truncated in the output. To be sure of a clean output I want to convert the Matrix into a dataframe containing each column of the matrix on an individual column.

Comment: @djWann: Did you try using `df.show(false)`? It won't truncate the output.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't truncate the output, but in the zeppelin cell it's very hard to understand because of the 50 columns.

Comment: 50 columns in an Wrapped Array I mean.

Comment: @djWann: I see. I changed the solution to build a dataframe that has each value as a separate column. Hope it helps!