# How to plot correlation heatmap when using pyspark+databricks

Tags: ggplot2, pyspark, heatmap, correlation, databricks

I am studying pyspark in databricks. I want to generate a correlation heatmap. Let's say this is my data:

```
myGraph=spark.createDataFrame([(1.3,2.1,3.0),
                               (2.5,4.6,3.1),
                               (6.5,7.2,10.0)],
                              ['col1','col2','col3'])
```

And this is my code:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from ggplot import *
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.stat import Correlation
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics

myGraph=spark.createDataFrame([(1.3,2.1,3.0),
                               (2.5,4.6,3.1),
                               (6.5,7.2,10.0)],
                              ['col1','col2','col3'])
vector_col = "corr_features"
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['col1','col2','col3'], 
                            outputCol=vector_col)
myGraph_vector = assembler.transform(myGraph).select(vector_col)
matrix = Correlation.corr(myGraph_vector, vector_col)
matrix.collect()[0]["pearson({})".format(vector_col)].values
```

Until here, I can get the correlation matrix. The result looks like:

[image]

Now my problems are:

1. How to transfer matrix to data frame? I have tried the methods of [How to convert DenseMatrix to spark DataFrame in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54103400/how-to-convert-densematrix-to-spark-dataframe-in-pyspark) and [How to get correlation matrix values pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831874/how-to-get-correlation-matrix-values-pyspark). But it does not work for me.
2. How to generate a correlation heatmap which looks like:

[image]

Because I just studied pyspark and databricks. ggplot or matplotlib are both OK for my problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the point where you get confused is:

```
matrix.collect()[0]["pearson({})".format(vector_col)].values
```

Calling .values of a densematrix gives you a list of all values, but what you are actually looking for is a list of list representing correlation matrix.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.stat import Correlation

columns = ['col1','col2','col3']

myGraph=spark.createDataFrame([(1.3,2.1,3.0),
                               (2.5,4.6,3.1),
                               (6.5,7.2,10.0)],
                              columns)
vector_col = "corr_features"
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['col1','col2','col3'], 
                            outputCol=vector_col)
myGraph_vector = assembler.transform(myGraph).select(vector_col)
matrix = Correlation.corr(myGraph_vector, vector_col)
```

Until now it was basically your code. Instead of calling .values you should use .toArray().tolist() to get a list of lists representing the correlation matrix:

```
matrix = Correlation.corr(myGraph_vector, vector_col).collect()[0][0]
corrmatrix = matrix.toArray().tolist()
print(corrmatrix)
```

Output:

```
[[1.0, 0.9582184104641529, 0.9780872729407004], [0.9582184104641529, 1.0, 0.8776695567739841], [0.9780872729407004, 0.8776695567739841, 1.0]]
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can turn a list of lists easily into a dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(corrmatrix,columns)
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+------------------+------------------+------------------+ 
|              col1|              col2|              col3| 
+------------------+------------------+------------------+ 
|               1.0|0.9582184104641529|0.9780872729407004|
|0.9582184104641529|               1.0|0.8776695567739841| 
|0.9780872729407004|0.8776695567739841|               1.0|  
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

To answer your second question. Just one of the many solutions to plot a heatmap (like [this](https://www.kaggle.com/vijayprayagala/correlation-heat-map-and-scatter-matrix) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48278285/6664872) even better with [seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37790429/seaborn-heatmap-using-pandas-dataframe)).

```
def plot_corr_matrix(correlations,attr,fig_no):
    fig=plt.figure(fig_no)
    ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_title("Correlation Matrix for Specified Attributes")
    ax.set_xticklabels(['']+attr)
    ax.set_yticklabels(['']+attr)
    cax=ax.matshow(correlations,vmax=1,vmin=-1)
    fig.colorbar(cax)
    plt.show()

plot_corr_matrix(corrmatrix, columns, 234)
```

Comment: Cronoik - Do the values have to be in INT format? I'm attempting correlation between FLOAT values and getting NaN in the resulting matrix.

Comment: No, that is not necessary. I also have used float format in the example above. Can you please open your own question and show us your code? I will have a look at it.